# Better alternate for changing attribute and not updating it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, attributes

I was just curious that if we have some better alternate method to perform the following action on a `Instance` of any `Class` say `User` ?

```
user = User.first
user.first_name 
=> 'Sahil'
user.last_name 
=> 'Grover'
user.update_attributes(:name =>'Sahil',:last_name => 'Gr.')
```

This will update the name in the database. Is there some method to just perform

```
user.first_name = 'Sahil'
user.last_name = 'Gr. '
```

But not save it into the database. Although I don't see any practical implementation for this. Just wanted to know if there exists any such method ??

Comment: What's wrong with `user.name = 'Sahil Gr.'` ?

Comment: not sure what you want to say

Comment: @Baldrick check the updated question? What if I have to do this for 2 3 columns/attributes ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the method [`assign_attributes`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment.html#method-i-assign_attributes)

```
user.assign_attribute(:name =>'Sahil',:last_name => 'Gr.')
```

This is actually the method used by [`update_attributes`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/260471a5e1b00136fc2d6e66bab29059fc6d8174/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L222-L231)

Comment: assign_attribute doesn't work, its always update_attributes. assign_attribute throws NoMethodError: undefined method `assign_attribute' for #<User:0x00000006159040>